# convert source code to pdf with highlighting

Tags: php, pdf

i have a site where people can download source code, sorta paste type site, i want them to be able to download a pdf version, sorta on the fly type.

i been using dompdf for other projects, but it seems i cant do the highlighting, it tries to parse the actual php code.

ive used pdf24.org online converter and it does the highlighting, but since its not open source i cant implement it.

ive tried using highlight_file, but all it does is spit out the contents in the browser, even if i set output to false.

any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but you must set return to true if you want it returned in a string rather than output to the browser.

Comment: dompdf will parse PHP in your document if you do not set DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highlight_file` is correct,

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html = highlight_file(..., $return=true);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [enscript](http://www.markkurossi.com/genscript/). I've used it for printing source code to PDF and it does an excellent job. You can call it with a `system()` call if you need to do this from PHP.